# How to change a dataframe in R to a named list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe ("samp") in R with student IDs and the exams that each student did.

```
    student_id math_exam spanish_exam
       <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1          1       0         1
2          2       1         0
3          3       0         0
4          4       1         1
```

I would like to make a named list where I have the student ID and the names of the exams that the student has taken instead of the 0 and 1. So for student 1 it will show just the spanish exam but for student 4 it will show math exam, spanish exam.

I think I am close with using the replace command so I did some basic testing and see if I can just replace all the 1's with a column name:

```
    replace(samp, grepl(1, samp, perl=TRUE), names(samp)[2])
```

But instead I replaced everything with the same column name like so:

```
   student_id math_exam spanish_exam
 1  math_exam math_exam    math_exam
 2  math_exam math_exam    math_exam
 3  math_exam math_exam    math_exam
 4  math_exam math_exam    math_exam
```

I tried to just specify a column like samp$math_exam but get the same results. Is using replace a good idea?  I am still fairly new with R so apologies if I'm asking too much.  Any guidance on this would be wonderful! Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your desired output too please?

Comment: Have you considered converting "math_exam" and "spanish_exam" columns to factors? You can do this by `samp$math_exam = factor(samp$math_exam, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("no_math_exam", "math_exam"))`

Comment: I think you meant `replace(samp$math_exam, samp$math_exam == 1, names(samp)[2])` This only replaces "math_exam". Not sure exactly what output you looking for.

Comment: the  data seems to be  a `tibble` and not a plain data.frame, is it so? automatic casting to dataframe will work, even then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to slice the data.frame, melt the dataset to a long format and return only the exams taken.

```
library(tidyr)

xy <- data.frame(student_id = 1:4, math_exam = c(0, 1, 0, 1), spanish_exam = c(1, 0, 0, 1))

xy <- split(xy, xy$student_id)

result <- lapply(xy, FUN = function(x) {
  out <- gather(x, key = exam, value = taken, -student_id)
  out[out$taken == 1, ][, -3]
})

do.call(rbind, result)

    student_id         exam
1            1 spanish_exam
2            2    math_exam
4.1          4    math_exam
4.2          4 spanish_exam
```

If you fancy a `dplyr` solution...

```
library(dplyr)

xy %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  gather(key = exam, value = taken, -student_id) %>%
  filter(taken == 1) %>%
  select(-taken)

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: student_id [3]

  student_id         exam
       <int>        <chr>
1          2    math_exam
2          4    math_exam
3          1 spanish_exam
4          4 spanish_exam
```

Comment: Exactly same came to my mind... you won, though! I always love `dplyr` and here you gave another reason to it why!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `melt` function from `reshape2` package to melt the dataframe and subset for `value == 1`. Splitting the resulting data frame on `student_id` we get a list with different students and their exams, i.e.

```
library(reshape2)
d3 <- melt(d1, id.vars = 'student_id')
d3 <- d3[d3$value == 1,][-3]
split(d3, d3$student_id)

#$`1`
#  student_id     variable
#5          1 spanish_exam

#$`2`
#  student_id  variable
#2          2 math_exam

#$`4`
#  student_id     variable
#4          4    math_exam
#8          4 spanish_exam

#You can also split on variable to get a list of exams rather than a list of students, i.e.

split(d3, d3$variable)

#$math_exam
#    student_id  variable
#  2          2 math_exam
#  4          4 math_exam

#$spanish_exam
#  student_id     variable
#5          1 spanish_exam
#8          4 spanish_exam
```

**DATA**

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(student_id = 1:4, math_exam = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), spanish_exam = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("student_id", 
"math_exam", "spanish_exam"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: huh? how is tha different @ManojKumar? Other than exam columns being numeric rather than integer?

Comment: @ManojKumar care to elaborate?

Comment: I am not taking it wrong. I am just (still) trying to understand what you mean.